# How to parse datetime format json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a datetime json string `2014-05-06T12:13.23Z` How can I parse this json string to the following?

```
2014-05-06 12:13.23
```

Comment: `'2014-05-06T12:13.23Z'.replace('T',' ').replace('Z','')`

Comment: @chridam No at least above doesn't work on Chrome

Comment: @Satpal you might consider modifying your solution to below:'2014-05-06T12:13.23Z'.replace('T',' ').replace('Z','').replace(".",":")

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan, Why would I do so? Its works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/MQNL5/

Comment: @Satpal right.the parsing works right. but it doesn't return a date object. It is just string. Ideally one would want to have a date object ready to be manipulated later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try below:

```
var dateStr = "2014-05-06T12:13.23Z";
var time = Date.parse(dateStr.replace('T',' ').replace('Z','').replace(".",":"));
var date = new Date(time); 
alert(date.getFullYear() +"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate()+" " 
      +date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds());
```